# Recovering lost AWS EC2 Key Pairs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keys, key-pair

AWS rookie here. I created a few EC2 instances under my AWS account and reused the same Key Pair for all of them. I *believe* (IIRC) that I had generated the Key Pair from inside AWS, but that could be wrong.

Over this past weekend I sold my old laptop (after completely wiping the hard disk) and got a new one. I'm just remembering now (`:facepalm`) that I forgot to copy all my SSH private keys to a flash drive and that I no longer have them.

All I want/need to do is to SSH into my EC2 instances, but to do that I need my SSH keys. I still have AWS console access, and I can log in and view all my EC2 Key Pairs. But I don't see any options for downloading them or updating my EC2 instances with new Key Pairs.

**So I ask:**

1. Is it possible for me to recover my existing Key Pairs somehow so that I can SSH into my EC2 instances? Again I can log into the AWS console. *If not, then...*
2. Is it possible to generate another Key Pair and "swap it out" for my existing Key Pair?

I really don't want to have to tear down my old EC2 instances and re-provision new ones, that will take about a week for me to do (although, arguably, it would serve me right!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rebuild shouldnt be nesserary. Id suggest option 2 as its quicker and easier.

1.> Its possible to change/append a new key?

- Power off the ec2 instance you want to access ("target").
- Create a new ("temporary") instance.
- Detach the primary EBS volume from target instance (taking note of its current attachment!).
- Attach/mount target volume on temporary instance.
- edit appropriate authorized_keys file on the mounted volume.
- unmount target volume, and reattach to target ec2 instance (using config you noted when detatching it)
- start target instance and login with new key.
- delete temporary instance

2.> Yes. Snapshot the instance. Provision a new instance from the snapshot selecting a different key (keypair popup appears when you click launch at end of launch wizard)

Comment: interesting approach

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Go to IAM.
- Step 2: Create a policy with the permission
  "AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore".
- Step 3: Create a new role and attach
  the previously created policy to that role.
- Step 4: Go to EC2, select
  the instance in "Actions" ==> "Security" ==> "Modify IAM role" select
  the created role and save.
- Step 5: Wait for 1 hour. It will take some
  time to resolve.
- Step 6: Select the EC2, Click on "Connect" ==>
  "Session Manager" ==> "Connect"

You will get a session with that session you can add a new key to authorized keys.

Answer (score 0):

Change ec2 user data to a multipart mime.

Parts:

- cloud config

```
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]
```

- shell script

Overwrites /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys

Refer to this blog article [replace ec2 ssh key](https://exagriddba.wpcomstaging.com/2021/02/21/replace-ec2-ssh-key/)

Answer (score -1):

You can replace the new key using user data or systems manager.

Using User Data:

1. Create a new key pair from the AWS EC2 Console
2. Generate the Public Key from the downloaded key pair using below cmd:
   ssh-keygen -y -f .pem
3. Stop the EC2 instance and edit the user data of the instance and pass the below script and start the Instance

   ```
   Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
   MIME-Version: 1.0

   --//
   Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
   MIME-Version: 1.0
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

   #cloud-config
   cloud_final_modules:
   - [users-groups, once]
   users:
    - name:ec2-user
      ssh-authorized-keys:
      - <**Paste the Public key here**>
   ```

   Now, You will be able to login to EC2 instance with the downloaded key pair.

Using Systems Manager:

1. If the instance is a managed instance in AWS Systems Manager, you can use the AWSSupport-ResetAccess document to recover the lost key pair.
2. Open the AWS Systems Manager console, select Automation in left navigation pane, click execute Automation. In automation document section select owned by Amazon. In the run book list, search for AWSSupport-ResetAccess
3. In Execute automation document page, choose Simple execution. In document details section, verify Document version is set to Default. In the input parameter section, specify the Instance ID, Subnet ID and Instance type in parameter and execute.
4. When Automation is finished, the new ssh private key is saved and encrypted in parameter store and the parameter store named as /ec2rl/openssh//key

You can refer the below link for more detailed steps:

https://cloudsolutionsonline.blogspot.com/2021/11/connect-to-linux-ec2-instance-if-ssh.html?m=1

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30337064)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, provided step by step instruction