# Why EC2 is giving me public key it won't accept?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm wrestling with SSH keys here. I'm trying to SSH into my instance on EC2 so I created
new key pair and dowloaded as well. Moved the `pem` file into `~/.ssh/key.pem` and ran:

`sudo chmod 400 key.pem` as required by AWS.

and to test it:

`ssh -i "~/.ssh/key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-3-x-y-228.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` x & y are replaced by real values

output:  `Permission denied (public key)`

What am I doing wrong ? This is pretty straightforward operation. Thank you.

**-vvv output:**

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "ec2-3-x-y-228.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to ec2-3-x-y-228.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [3.9.13.228] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mark/.ssh/key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mark/.ssh/key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-3-x-y-228.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/mark/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/mark/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-3-9-13-228.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:r/f7fqemYF3CfPl9S+8wDMN1UtsqrtYRaX1tkWaEwlk
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/mark/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/mark/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-3-9-13-228.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/mark/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/mark/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 3.9.13.228
debug1: Host 'ec2-3-x-y-228.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/mark/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: desktop ED25519 SHA256:inJuopb8NVP9ctfF1iGEWI3jz/dIvg9KtFJ5PIZA1CA agent
debug1: Will attempt key: desktop ED25519 SHA256:RpPez0H8w3OHcsJhQl9u/X/RQtokQqGBM9Uwyq/0uqA agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/mark/.ssh/key.pem  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: desktop ED25519 SHA256:inJuopb8NVP9ctfF1iGEWI3jz/dIvg9KtFJ5PIZA1CA agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: desktop ED25519 SHA256:RpPez0H8w3OHcsJhQl9u/X/RQtokQqGBM9Uwyq/0uqA agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mark/.ssh/key.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:+cjeAT0FFDXzcLAEh+QsN3UXgKdN/RVey39Lzuj1Q60
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:+cjeAT0FFDXzcLAEh+QsN3UXgKdN/RVey39Lzuj1Q60
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ubuntu@ec2-3-x-y-228.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: You use the *private* key to authenticate. The public key is used on the system to which you are connecting. Just use `-i ~/.ssh/key.pem`.

Comment: @larsks  Same error output.

Comment: @Mark, if you've corrected the simple problem of using the wrong key file, please [edit] your question to show what what you're now doing and what is now happening. It would be helpful to run `ssh` with the "-vv" flag to print debugging output, then [edit] your question to include the output.

Comment: @Kenster  Edited. The verbose debug output hasn't revealed anything helpful. Has it ?

Comment: There's not really much information in that verbose output: it simply says that ssh presented a public key, and the key was rejected. That can mean (a) you're using the wrong private key, or (b) the wrong username, or (c) something on the remote server is incorrectly configured. Typically, the next step for diagnosing this sort of problem would be to run `sshd` on the server in debug mode, but that obviously requires successful access to the server first.

Comment: @Mark, have you resolved this issue? I am having the same error. It is a fresh EC2 VM, and my key is working for connecting to other instances, and obviously I can't connect to the fresh EC2 server using other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using SSH to connect to a remote system, the steps are:

- Your computer uses the **private key** to authenticate
- The remote computer looks in the `/usr/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and tries to find a matching **public key**
- If the keys match, the SSH session will be established

Therefore, it appears that the public half of the keypair has not been inserted into the `/usr/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote computer. This is normally done automatically for you when a new instance is launched. However, if you want to use a different keypair *after the instance has been launched*, then you are responsible for adding that keypair to the `authorized_keys` file on the remote computer.

To do this, you either need an existing login to the remote computer (using an *existing* keypair) or you could copy the keypair by stopping the instance, moving the boot disk to another instance, editing the file, then put the disk back and start the computer. See: [Recovering lost AWS EC2 Key Pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49761369/174777)

Comment: @KaiBurjack  On machines that are being connected to they get `autorized_keys` file and the machine that is connecting has the `known_hosts` file. I have that file in `~/.ssh`.

Comment: I'm using Docker Machine's API to create EC2 instances so in that case I don't know if the public key is automatically being inserted into `authorized_keys` on the instance. I'm gonna try to recreate the instance and see if the public gets inserted automatically.

Comment: I strongly believe that's what's happening to me. I've got bunch of keys but I had no clue I need to insert the public key manually into the instance which is kinda funny 'coz for that you need SSH access too :D I best off just recreate the instance and let EC2 insert the key for me.